# How to close onscreen nav buttons forcefully? Meteor Cordova

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-cordova

onscreen nav buttons (back, home and overview) automatically opens with keyboard but doesn’t close as the keyboard closes on android devices.

[Please see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gww17.jpg)

Image 1. Initially when the keyboard is close.

Image 2. When the keyboard opens. Nav bar opens automatically.

Image 3. When I close the keyboard. Nav bar still remains open.

Image 4. Even after submitting the form and redirecting to next page, the nav bar remains open.

Comment: Please share your activity file code.

Comment: What's an activity file?